# bruteforce attack inside iFrame

Tags: brute-force, iframe, lfi

How can I change the value of `src` parameter inside the `iFrame` tag with programs like `wfuzz` or `fuff`?

For example I have an `iFrame` on the server like this:

iframe.php

```
<html>
<head><title>attack to iFrame</title></head>
<body>

<h1> iFrame Attack !!! </h1>

<iframe src="test.php" width="72%"></iframe> 

</body>
</html>
```

and is it possible to access system files via `iFrame` ?

something like this :

```
<iframe src="file://etc/passwd" width="72%"></iframe>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: No web fuzzer can change a static file. If the relevant part is not generated dynamically it will stay the same.

Comment: Inspecting in the browser (client) can only show what the server sends to the client.

Comment: you can use tampermonkey to do that in js.